# How can i generate a Swagger json file of Woocommerce REST Api?

Tags: c#, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, swagger

I have a .NET (C#) desktop application and I need to connect this with an existing Woocommerce website. I am familiar with Swagger. Swagger generates the class definitions along with HttpClient execution code of the remote endpoints, so I wanted to consume the Woocommerce rest api endpoints through a swagger json file. But unfortunately Woocommerce doesn't support Swagger file yet (this is what I understood by seeing their documentation). 
I have tried to use

> **http://mywcommercesite.com/wp-json/wc/v1**

but no luck as it is not a Swagger file.

So, my question is, should I try to generate the swagger file by myself manually, or is there anything which will generate the swagger file for me after feeding it the above type of URL. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this plugin that will generate swagger UI for all the WP API
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-swaggerui/

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Try to elaborate how this link should be used/